# Составление шаблона для регулярных выражений

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка, например "a, bc1d, fe'g h23q d".
Нужно подобрать такой шаблон, что будет возвращена строка (вернее, будут найдены совпадения):
"a" "bc" "d" "fe'g" "h" "q" "d".
Иными словами, из любого предложения нужно выделить *только* слова (слова с апострофом it's выводятся как одно "it's"), минуя все остальные символы (специальные, знаки препинания, числа и пробелы).
Задача в целом несложная, мне удалось написать такой шаблон (язык C#, однако синтаксис регулярных выражений в целом похож во многих языках):

```
var myFilter = new Regex(@"\w+[']\w|\w+(?!\d)");
```

Его недостаток в том, что он не считает числа разделителями.
Подскажите, как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон `\w` (=`[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Pc}]`) находит буквы, цифры, знаки подчёркивания и диакритические знаки (см. [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w)).

Чтобы найти только буквы, используйте `\p{L}`:

```cs
\p{L}+(?:'\p{L}+)*
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%28%3F%3A%27%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%29*&i=a%2C%20bc1d%2C%20fe%27g%20h23q%20d).

- `\p{L}+` - одна и более букв
- `(?:'\p{L}+)*` - ноль и более повторов последовательности `'` и одной и более букв.

Comment: Извините, я забыл отметить одну деталь: "ab'1" должно вернуть "ab'"...

Comment: @TheBadBat Тогда сделайте буквенный шаблон в подмаске необязательным, `\p{L}+(?:'\p{L}*)*` или `\p{L}+(?:'\p{L}*)?`.

Comment: Это повлияет на количество совпадений? Т.е. 0 или 1 совпадений с определенной частью шаблона, верно я понимаю?

Comment: @TheBadBat Их будет столько же. См. [пример](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cp%7bL%7d%2b%28%3f%3a%27%5cp%7bL%7d*%29*&i=a%2c+bc1d%2c+fe%27g+h23q+d+ab%271).

Comment: Еще небольшое уточнение: а как быть в случае, если необходимо считать апостроф как слово? То есть в случае " ' " вывод был бы '
Естественно, с сохранением всех предыдущих условий.

Comment: @TheBadBat Тогда, может, не надо и заморачиваться особо, используйте `[\p{L}']+` и всё.

Comment: Все, разобрался. Спасибо за помощь:)